# Architectural issue: Design of recurring events

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, recurring

I need to have a logic in our app, which allows to define recurring events (e.g. every tuesday, oder every 1st day of a month) which lead then to a specific action in the app.

I thought UILocalNotification would be a good idea, but with this class I send a notification also to the user and I want to process the event **only** in the app (If the app is not online, then may be the next time the app is up)

Another idea was to set up a list with the event and check every time the app is up, whether an event is due - but this seems quite old fashioned - hope there is something better.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to use `UILocalNotification` in your situation, it will completely fulfill the needs that you described.

Since you said, the event should only fire whenever the app is active (*in foreground*) you will have to add some custom logic to make this happen, but this is not a very difficult task and you have multiple options here.

What I would suggest is that you use the *app lifecycle* methods of your `AppDelegate`, to schedule and remove your notifications when it's appropriate.

The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol contains two relevant methods for your case (actually a bit more, but these two will do the job for you...). First we have `applicationWillEnterBackground:`, that's where you should remove all currently scheduled notifications. In the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` you can then reschedule the notifications, as this one is called every time your app is coming to the foreground again.

Let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Did I understand right, that it would mean, that whenever the app become active,  I reschedule all existing notifications (there will be about 20 to 50 different schedules which were inputed once)  and delete them when the app becomes not active anymore?( As I very much appreciate your answer, I somehow had the hope of an easier solution)

Comment: well, ideally you encapsulate the logic to (re)schedule notifications into a dedicated class (e.g. `NotificationManager`). that way, you only have to implement the logic once, and then just reuse the instance of that class in your `AppDelegate`. this should only be one method call in both `applicationWillEnterBackground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, something like `[notificationManager scheduleNotifications]` and `[notificationManager removeNotifications]`

Comment: `NotificationManager` is the class that always knows how many notifications to schedule, and when to schedule them, your `AppDelegate` only calls its methods

Comment: And one more addition, since you have said it'll be between 20 and 50 notifications to be scheduled, you might want to do it in a background thread using `performSelector:withObject:`, this could look like this: `[notificationManager performSelector:@selector(scheduleNotifications) withObject:nil]`

Comment: Hi, yes I got it, thanks again, will give it a try and let you know.  Have a good day

Comment: Great, if it's clear, could you please mark the question as answered :)